# how to create matrix like combination of rows and columns

Tags: c#, vb.net

i have one requirement.
May i know how to put matrix in vb.net.
like
sno|column1|column2|column2

is thee any control in vb.net
i never seen any control like this 
is there any way .

Answer (score 0):

Convert `matrix` into `dataset` and bind it with `grid-view`.

Comment: what i am asking is is there any tool in tool box .

Comment: i want to put matrix  like  sno|column| column2| after that the should able to enter data into the each column and then i want to save data to the sql after click on submit button

Comment: @SrinivasRachumallu i think u are looking for grid control and do your sql operations in button event.

Comment: i need combobox too in matrix i mean grid is it possible. Any information plz update me.